# Can I borrow values into a closure instead of moving them?

Tags: rust, lmdb, actix-web

I'm writing a GET method for a server application written in [actix-web](https://github.com/actix/actix-web). [LMDB](https://docs.rs/lmdb-rkv/0.12.3/lmdb/) is the database I use, its transactions need to be aborted or committed before the end of their lifetime.

In order to avoid a bunch of nested `match`ing, I tried using `map_err` on all of the functions that return a result. There I try to abort the transaction, but the transaction gets moved into the closure instead of being borrowed.

Is there any way to instead borrow the transaction into the closure, or do I have to bite the bullet and write a bunch of nested matches? Essentially, what's the most ergonomic way to write this function?

Example code (see comments next to `txn.abort()`):

```rust
pub async fn get_user(db: Data<Database>, id: Identity) -> Result<Json<User>, Error> {
    let username = id.identity().ok_or_else(|| error::ErrorUnauthorized(""))?;

    let txn = db
        .env
        .begin_ro_txn()
        .map_err(|_| error::ErrorInternalServerError(""))?;

    let user_bytes = txn.get(db.handle_users, &username).map_err(|e| {
        txn.abort(); // txn gets moved here

        match e {
            lmdb::Error::NotFound => {
                id.forget();
                error::ErrorUnauthorized("")
            }
            _ => error::ErrorInternalServerError(""),
        }
    })?;

    let user: User = serde_cbor::from_slice(user_bytes).map_err(|_| {
        txn.abort(); // cannot use txn here as is was moved
        error::ErrorInternalServerError("")
    })?;

    txn.abort(); // cannot use txn here as is was moved
    Ok(Json(user))
}
```

Comment: No, you can't do this, since `abort` consumes transaction, so it has to be moved into the closure

Comment: If you want to improve the ergonomics of nested matches, you can look at crates like [map_for](https://crates.io/crates/map_for) or [mdo](https://crates.io/crates/mdo) (Full disclosure: I wrote map_for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, in my case it is impossible to borrow the value into the closure, because `abort` consumes the transaction. (Thanks to @vkurchatkin for explaining that)

In case anyone is interested, I've worked out a solution that satisfies me regardless of the issue. It was possible for me to avoid nesting a bunch of `match`es.

I moved all of the logic that works on the transaction into a separate function and then delayed the evaluation of the function `Result` until after running `txn.abort()` (see comments):

```rust
pub async fn get_user(db: Data<Database>, id: Identity) -> Result<Json<User>, Error> {
    let username = id.identity().ok_or_else(|| error::ErrorUnauthorized(""))?;

    let txn = db
        .env
        .begin_ro_txn()
        .map_err(|_| error::ErrorInternalServerError(""))?;

    let user = db_get_user(&db, &txn, &id, &username); // Execute separate function but do not evaluate the function Result yet, notice missing question mark operator!
    txn.abort(); // Abort the transaction after running the code. (Doesn't matter if it was successful or not. This consumes the transaction and it cannot be used anymore.)
    Ok(Json(user?)) // Now evaluate the Result using the question mark operator.
}

// New separate function that uses the transaction.
fn db_get_user(
    db: &Database,
    txn: &RoTransaction,
    id: &Identity,
    username: &str,
) -> Result<User, Error> {
    let user_bytes = txn.get(db.handle_users, &username).map_err(|e| match e {
        lmdb::Error::NotFound => {
            id.forget();
            error::ErrorUnauthorized("")
        }
        _ => error::ErrorInternalServerError(""),
    })?;

    serde_cbor::from_slice(user_bytes).map_err(|_| error::ErrorInternalServerError(""))
}
```